# Replacing jQuery ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to replace the id of a jQuery element for the next one as follows:
'foo-1' --> 'foo-2'

And I finally ended with this:

```
$(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id').replace(/-[0-9]*/,'-'+(parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring($(this).attr('id').indexOf('-')+1,$(this).attr('id').length))+1)));
```

Ugly, right?
Any Ideas of how I would improve this.....?

Comment: I don't think that's your actual code; and if it is, it shouldn't be working: `lenght`?

Comment: attrs() is not a standard jquery method, is it a typo or are you using a custom method?

Comment: @Piskvor sorry, you are right, one typo :( #edited

Comment: @mamoo you are right, I mean "attr" #edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the replace callback function to simplify your code:

```
this.id = this.id.replace(/(-)(\d)*/, function ($1,$2,$3,$4) {
  console.log(arguments);
  var index = parseInt($3,10);
  return $2 + ++index + "";
});
```

`$2` matches the first parentheses (which is '-' in your case), `$3` matches the digitals. You then prase the digital with `parseInt()` and increment it by one. Finally, you put together the replaced string with `+` string operator.

Comment: Thanks dude.  Edited to include an explanation and a more general pattern replace.

Comment: Can someone point me to the documentation page of `.attrs()` method? jQuery documentation is silent about that method.

Comment: @Tadeck Sorry for the typos. Correct it with the right `.attr()` function.

Comment: Easy-reader: `this.id = this.id.replace(/(-)(\d)*/, func...` (cf. [Utilizing the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an element](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element))

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id'),
    num = parseInt(id, 10),
    next = num + 1,
    string = id.substring(0, id.length - num.length) + next;


$(this).attr('id', string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
var num = parseInt( $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
var newid = id.replace(num, '') + (num + 1);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xH7Rf/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
var el = jQuery(this);
var old_id = el.attr('id');
var id_number = parseInt(old_id.match(/\d/), 10);
el.attr('id', old_id.replace(id_number, id_number+1));
```

This has multiple advantages over your code:

- it caches element you are processing (as `el`),
- it caches processed ID of the element (as `old_id`),
- it is very clean and readable,
- it even uses less letters than your code,

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnsY9/) for a proof of changing IDs into ones with higher integer in them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr('id',
function() {
    var me = this;
    return $(me).attr('id').replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + (parseInt($(me).index() + 1));
});

// this code snippet will assign id to element if it possess any id (like: foo-1/foo-2) or not

$(this).attr('id',
function() {
    var me = this;
    return ($(me).attr('id') ? $(me).attr('id').replace(/[0-9]/g, '') : 'foo-') + (parseInt($(me).index() + 1));
});
```